# eclipse-mosquitto "Address in use" with v2.0.12

Tags: docker, mosquitto

I'm updatet my mosquitto from v1.6.9 to v2.0.12. But now, I'm not able to send mqtt messagtes with this docker container.

docker-container run:

```
docker run -itd \
--name="mosquitto" \
--restart always \
-p 1883:1883 \
-v /home/pi/.docker/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf \
-v mosquitto_data:/mosquitto/data \
-v mosquitto_data:/mosquitto/log \
eclipse-mosquitto
```

my config file:

```
listener 1883
allow_anonymous true
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log
```

The permissions for config file (in docker container): 644 mosquitto:mosquitto

In log I see following output:

```
0: mosquitto version 2.0.12 starting 
0: Using default config. 
0: Starting in local only mode. Connections will only be possible from clients running on this machine. 
0: Create a configuration file which defines a listener to allow remote access. 
0: For more details see https://mosquitto.org/documentation/authentication-methods/
0: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883. 
0: Error: Address in use 
0: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883. 
0: Error: Address not available
```

If I pub a new message I got an unknown error

> ```
> # mosquitto_pub -t 'test/topic' -m 'hello, is anybody out there?'
> Error: Unknown error.
> ```

It seems it doesn't load my config-file. see "0: Using default config".
Or is it something else? Maybe the permissions of the config file?

Thx

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you have stopped and removed the old 1.6.9 container? Also what is the default network mode set to?

Comment: yes, I am. Also network mode was not the problem.
Source was that with the newer alpine image, libseccomp2 needed an update on Raspbian.

Details see here: https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/2323#issuecomment-927367047

After that, it seems to run without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source was that with the newer alpine image, libseccomp2 needed an update on Raspbian.

Details see here: https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/2323#issuecomment-927367047

After that, it runs without any further problems.