# Docker Mosquitto won't load custom config file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mqtt, mosquitto

The goal is to run a mosquitto broker in docker that should subscribe to a topic published by a different device in the same network. The host OS is Centos (minimal install).
Unfortunatley there are **two problems**:

1. Mosquitto is not loading my custom mosquitto.conf I provided in the docker-compose.yml
2. `"Error: Address in use"` – Even though there is no other Mosquitto service running on the host or different container. (Checked with `netstat -tunlp` and `docker ps -a`)

I hope that the "Address in use" error will be resolved once the proper configuration in loaded? I would be really thankful, if someone could point me in the right direction. Am I overlooking something?

```bash
1681677658: mosquitto version 2.0.15 starting
1681677658: Using default config.
1681677658: Starting in local only mode. Connections will only be possible from clients running on this machine.
1681677658: Create a configuration file which defines a listener to allow remote access.
1681677658: For more details see https://mosquitto.org/documentation/authentication-methods/
1681677658: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1681677658: Error: Address in use
1681677658: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1681677658: Error: Address not available
```

docker-compose.yml and mosquitto.conf:

```yaml
---
version: '3.7'

services:
  mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto
    container_name: mosquitto
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /opt/mosquitto/config:/mosquitto/config
      - /opt/mosquitto/mosquitto/data:/mosquitto/data
      - /opt/mosquitto/mosquitto/log:/mosquitto/log
    ports:
      - 1883:1883
      - 9001:9001
```

```
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log
listener 1883

## Authentication ##
allow_anonymous true
```

**What I tried so far:**

- Setting a user/password (`mosquitto_passwd -c /mosquitto/config/password.txt mqttuser` → edited the mosquitto.conf (allow_anonymous false & password_file /mosquitto/config/password.txt) → restarted the container)
- Placed the mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf in the docker-compose directory instead /opt and updated the docker-compose.yml accordingly
- Tried different folder paths, e.g. mosquitto/conf/mosquitto.conf
- Different paths in the docker-compose.yml, e.g. mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf
- Checked if my libseccomp is outdated (2.5.2-2.el9), since someone had a similar problem [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69297678/eclipse-mosquitto-address-in-use-with-v2-0-12)
- After each new attempt I removed the container and started new from scratch. Rebooted the machine.
- **Edit 1:** Running `$ sudo docker exec mosquitto ls -al /mosquitto/config`

  ```bash
  total 4
  drwxr-xr-x    2 mosquitt mosquitt        28 Apr 16 19:47 .
  drwxr-xr-x    1 mosquitt mosquitt         6 Mar 29 19:43 ..
  -rw-r--r--    1 mosquitt mosquitt       155 Apr 16 19:47 mosquitto.conf
  ```
- **Edit 2:** I ran the container with `image: eclipse-mosquitto:2.0.14` and `image: eclipse-mosquitto:2` – still the same error.

  ```bash
  $ docker image ls
  eclipse-mosquitto    2.0.14    e9f5cf5f8c52    8 months ago    11.8MB
  $ docker stop mosquitto && docker rm mosquitto && docker image rm e9f5cf5f8c52 && docker system prune
  $ docker compose up -d
  $ docker image ls
  eclipse-mosquitto    2.0.15    35a004f35c81    2 weeks ago     11.9MB
  ```
- **Edit 3:** Ran the docker-compose.yml with `network_mode: host` and without port mappings. Network was working, I could ping other devices. But still the same errors: `using default config` and `Error: Address in use`.
- **Edit 4:** After removing the old container and image, I am running it with `$ docker compose up -d` → `$ sudo docker exec -it mosquitto /bin/sh` → `mosquitto -v` (But I also checked the logs via `docker logs`)

  ```bash
  $ ps -ax | grep mosquitto
  315868 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto mosquitto

  $ sudo docker ps
  CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                        COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS                PORTS                                                                                                                                                                                    NAMES
  9f7d6b130b64   syncthing/syncthing                          "/bin/entrypoint.sh …"   6 days ago   Up 2 days (healthy)   0.0.0.0:8384->8384/tcp, 0.0.0.0:21027->21027/udp, :::8384->8384/tcp, :::21027->21027/udp, 0.0.0.0:22000->22000/tcp, :::22000->22000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:22000->22000/udp, :::22000->22000/udp   syncthing
  0fc19381338b   ghcr.io/paperless-ngx/paperless-ngx:latest   "/sbin/docker-entryp…"   6 days ago   Up 2 days (healthy)   0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp                                                                                                                                                paperless-webserver
  fe14e32c142b   postgres:13                                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 days ago   Up 2 days             5432/tcp                                                                                                                                                                                 paperless-postgres
  b7fe9d55b5de   redis:7                                      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 days ago   Up 2 days             6379/tcp                                                                                                                                                                                 paperless-redis
  9ed6e4265a1e   pihole/pihole:latest                         "/s6-init"               9 days ago   Up 2 days (healthy)   0.0.0.0:53->53/udp, :::53->53/udp, 0.0.0.0:53->53/tcp, :::53->53/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:67->67/udp, :::80->80/tcp, :::67->67/udp                                               pihole
  ```
- **Edit 5:** I changed the `listener` parameter in the mosquitto.conf from `listener 1883` to the loopback device IP: `listener 127.0.0.1:1883`.
  Weirdly the *Address in use* error is gone, even though mosquitto still seems to use only the default config file (`1682208581: Using default config.`).
  How that can be? Changes in the custom config file shouldn't have effects if mosquitto is loading only the default config file?

Comment: Please start your container then run `docker-compose exec mosquitto ls -al /mosquitto/config` (this will list the contents of the `/mosquitto/config` folder in the container) and add the output to your question. This may be a permissions issue - running `docker-compose exec mosquitto /bin/sh` will give you a shell within the container so you can check that the config files etc are where you expect (and accessible).

Comment: Done. `/ # vi /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf` opens the same mosquito.conf that I created outside the container.

Comment: Please run `docker-compose images` and let us know the image ID for Mosquitto. Your issue looks similar to [this](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/2777); It may be worth running `docker-compose pull`; if that does not help try pulling a specific version e.g. `image: eclipse-mosquitto:2.0.14`.

Comment: Can you try adding `network_mode: host` to your docker-compose.yml and see if that does anything? (This negates the need to have "ports" specified, as the docker container will use the host's network, and won't be isolated.)

Comment: Weird - can you please run `ps -ax | grep mosquitto`  on the host and show us the output? It might also be useful to document how you are running this (just `docker-compose up` and then `docker-compose logs`?). Could you also run `docker ps` (just in case there is another mosquitto container running).

Comment: There's also a comment in Mosquitto's source code saying it shouldn't be run as root. I added a non-root user to the container and added `USER myuser` to the Dockerfile, but still getting the exact same problem as OP describes.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. It seems when I installed mosquitto MQTT on my CasaOS debian box, the install put a start up at bootup. So when I tried to initiate in docker, the port was already used. I found it by using: `ps -aux | grep mosquitto`. That showed my container AND another instance running. I found the mosquitto.conf (etc/mosquitto) that the operating system used at boot up and put a line it to make the startup fail. I used `password_file /path/to/password/file` and since none of those things existed, the startup failed. I tried to eliminate the OS startup but never figured out how it was getting initiated. Then my docker instance of mosquitto code get port 1883 and all was good.

Comment: This is not my issue. If I remove the explicit startup of mosquitto, no mosquitto process runs. If I re-add the startup, only one mosquitto process is running.